# If $X^\ast $ is separable $\Longrightarrow$ $S_{X^\ast}$ is also separable

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space such that $X$* (Dual space of $X$) is separable

How can we prove that $S_{X^\ast}$ (Unit sphere of $X$*) is also separable

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: You can take a dense subset of the whole space and project it to the sphere by the map $x\rightarrow x/|x|$.

Comment: Off-topic ... a much more interesting question, worded the same, but considering the weak* topology.  If $X^\ast$ is weak* separable, does it follow that the unit ball is also?

Comment: @GEdgar: Nice question.  If you don't post it as one, then I will :)

Comment: @Nate: asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/408624/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:** here we consider the question for $X^*$, and $S_{X^*}$, equipped with the topology induced by the norm. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408624/weak-separable-question) for the same question with the weak* topology.

This is a consequence of a much more general fact which has nothing to do with duals and Banach spaces.

> **Fact:** if $(X,d)$ is a separable metric space, then for any subset $Y\subseteq X$, the subspace $(Y,d)$ is separable.

**Note:** as pointed out by Nate Eldredge, another approach is to observe that a subspace of a second countable space is obviously second countable. So it only remains to use or prove that a metric space is separable if and only it is second countable.

**Proof:** let $S=\{x_n\,;\,n\geq 1\}$ a dense subset of $X$. For every $n\geq 1$, consider the distance $d(x_n,Y)=\inf\{d(x_n,y)\,;\,y\in Y\}$. By definition of an infimum=greatest lower bound, for every $k\geq 1$, $d(x_n,Y)+\frac{1}{k}$ is not a lower bound of $\{d(x_n,y)\,;\,y\in Y\}$.  So there exists $y_n^k\in Y$ such that $d(x_n,y_n^k)< d(x_n,Y)+\frac{1}{k}$.

Since $T=\{y_n^k\,;\,n\geq 1, k\geq 1\}$ is a countable union of countable sets, it is countable. We will now show that it is dense in $Y$.

Take $y\in Y$ and $\epsilon>0$. By density of $S$ in $X$, there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $d(x_n,y)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. In particular, $d(x_n,Y)\leq d(x_n,y)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So for $k$ large enough, precisely: $k>\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}-d(x_n,Y)\right)^{-1}$, we have $d(x_n,Y)+\frac{1}{k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then for this $n$ and such a $k$, we get
$$
d(y_n^k,y)\leq d(y_n^k,x_n)+d(x_n,y)<d(x_n,Y)+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.
$$
So there are elements of $T$ arbitrarily close to $y$ for every $y\in Y$. That is $T$ is dense in $Y$. QED.

**Remark:** what really is about Banach spaces $X$ such that $X^*$ is separable is that $X$ is separable. And it follows that the unit sphere of $X$, $S_X$, is separable as well.

Comment: Another argument: a metric space is separable iff it is second countable (has a countable base).  And it's clear that any subset of a second countable space is itself second countable (intersect the base with the subset).

Comment: @NateEldredge Right. I should have added that. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this argument require that the weak* topology on $X^*$ be metrizable? And is that true?

Comment: Yes, but the question is about the unit sphere in $X^*$, not $X$?

Comment: Ah, now I see. I came here via that other question, so my mind was primed to see the weak* topology. My mistake.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen No problem. I've edited to make that clearer.