# Is $X^\ast$ is weak* separable equivalent to $B_{X^\ast}$ is weak* separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory, banach-spaces

(In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407339/442) Nate Eldredge said I should ask this.)

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $X^\ast$ the dual space, and $B_{X^\ast}$ the unit ball of $X^\ast$.  In the weak* topology for $X^\ast$, does one of these imply the other?

(a)  $X^\ast$ is weak* separable

(b) $B_{X^\ast}$ is weak* separable

Comment: If $\overline{D} = B_{X^\ast}$ then $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nD} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nB_{X^\ast} = X^\ast$, so (b) implies (a).

Comment: @Martin: Indeed. Just a nitpick: Write that as $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nD} \supseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nB_{X^\ast} = X^\ast$, since the closure of a union does not necessarily equal the union of the closures. The conclusion is unchanged by this, of course.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Right, that was a bit of a sloppy way of writing it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: In light of Martin's answer I've added the [tag:set-theory] tag.

Comment: I know an answer, and (if necessary) will post it eventually.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not sure why the tag (set-theory) is suitable here. Is it because of using: "union of countably many countable sets is countable"? Then probably (elementary-set-theory) would be better. (I have asked this also in the [tagging chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/4/24).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The paper cited by Martin (Avilés, Plebanek,  Rodríguez) uses some pretty heavy set theory.  Though GEdgar gives a solution that doesn't.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6):

(b) implies (a):

Let $D$ be a countable dense set in $B_{X^\ast}$. Then $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nD} \supseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nB_{X^\ast} = X^\ast$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nD$ is countable.

(a) does not imply (b):

*provided* the preprint Antonio Avilés, Grzegorz Plebanek, José Rodríguez, *[A weak* separable $C(K)^\ast$ space whose unit ball is not weak* separable](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5710)* (2011) is correct. I don't know if there are easier examples among less special spaces than C(K)*-spaces. If I interpret the introduction correctly, reference [14] could contain further examples.

Comment: Very nice reference!  It appears the paper of Avilés, Plebanek and Rodríguez has been accepted by *Transactions of the AMS* (see [here](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/mstrack/accepted_papers?jrnl=tran)) so that is some evidence in favor of its correctness.

Comment: But earlier examples exist where the space is not required to be of the form $C(K)$ ...

Comment: @GEdgar: yes, I believe you. As I said, I don't know. If you know, then why don't you indicate what they are instead of just pointing out their existence?

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is the answer I know.  This explanation is essentially copied from my paper ("Measurability in a Banach space, II."   *Indiana Univ. Math. J.* **28** (1979) 559--579 [LINK](http://dx.doi.org/10.1512/iumj.1979.28.28039)) Example 5.6.  But the space comes from a paper of W. B. Johnson & J. Lindenstrauss ("Some remarks on weakly compactly generated Banach spaces." *Israel J. Math.* **17** (1974), 219–230. [LINK](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=417760))

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

In $l^\infty$, let $e_n$ be the unit vector $e_n(k) = \delta_{kn}$.  Let $\{A_\gamma : \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ be an uncountable collection of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, such that the intersection of any two is finite.

> **aside.**  For example, consider the infinite binary tree.  It has countably many nodes, but uncountably many branches.  Let the nodes be indexed by $\mathbb N$ and let the branches be the sets $A_\gamma$.

Let $\varphi_\gamma \in l^\infty$ be the characteristic function of $A_\gamma$.  For finite linear combinations, define a norm
$$
\left\|\sum c_\gamma \varphi_\gamma + \sum b_n e_n\right\| = \max\left(
\left\|\sum c_\gamma \varphi_\gamma + \sum b_n e_n\right\|_\infty,
\left(\sum|c_\gamma|^2\right)^{1/2}\right) .
$$
Let $X$ be the completion of these finite linear combinations under this norm.
The closed linear span $X_0$ of $\{e_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$, and $X/X_0$ is isomorphic to $l^2(\Gamma)$.  The dual of $X$ is isomorphic to $l^1 \oplus l^2(\Gamma)$; the pairing identifies the unit vectors of $l^1$ with the linear functionals $e_n^\ast(f) = f(n)$, and the unit vectors of $l^2(\Gamma)$ with the linear functionals $e_\gamma^\ast(f) = \lim_{n \in A_\gamma} f(n)$.

The countable set $\{e_n^\ast : n \in \mathbb N\} \subset X^\ast$ separates points of $X$, so its rational linear span is a countable set that is weak* dense in $X^\ast$.

$X$ admits no countable norming set of functionals, since any countable subset of $X^*$ is contained in $l^1 \oplus l^2(\Gamma_0)$ for some countable $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$.

> **definition.** A *norming set* for $X$ is a set $R \subseteq B_{X^\ast}$ such that for all $x \in X$,$$\|x\| = \sup\{|u(x)|: u \in R\} .$$

To show that $B_{X^\ast}$ is not weak* separable, it suffices to show:
any weak* dense subset of $B_{X^\ast}$ is a norming set.  Indeed, let $R$ be weak* dense in $B_{X^\ast}$.  Let $x_0 \in X$.  Write $\|x_0\| = \alpha$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.  Since $R$ is a norming set, there exists $u_0 \in R$ with $|u_0(x_0)| \gt \alpha - \epsilon$.  Replacing $x_0$ by $-x_0$ if necessary, we may assume $u_0(x_0)$ is positive.  The set
$$
T_\epsilon := \{ u \in B_{X^\ast}: u(x_0)>\alpha-\epsilon\}
$$
is a nonempty weak* open set in $B_{X^\ast}$.  Since $R$ is weak* dense, we have $R \cap T_\epsilon \ne \varnothing$.  So
$$
\sup\{ |u(x_0)|: u \in R\} \gt \alpha - \epsilon .
$$
This is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, so
$$
\sup\{ |u(x_0)|: u \in R\} \ge \alpha = \|x_0\|,
$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks for adding this example. Of course this is much simpler than the one I found.

Comment: There is also "Weak star separability" by E.N. Dancer and B. Sims, BULL.AUSTRAL.MATH.SOC.(1979). The authors use the Johnson-Lindenstrauss example as well.