# Is $X$ separable iff $S_X=\{x\in X \mid ||x||=1\}$ separable?

Tags: functional-analysis

While going through [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407339/if-x-ast-is-separable-longrightarrow-s-x-ast-is-also-separable) in math stackexchange I have come across the fact that "if $(X,d)$ is a separable metric space, then for any subset $Y\subseteq X$, the subspace $(Y,d)$ is separable" which is mentioned in the answer by [1015](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38053/1015) to the same question.

After reading that question, I have stuck in a question. My question is : is it true that

> For a normed linear space $X$, $X$ is separable iff $S_X=\{x\in X \mid ||x||=1\}$ is separable.

I managed to get the same result for the unit ball $B_X=\{x\in X \mid ||x||<1\}$ But not quite sure about $S_X$. I think it is true for $S_X$ also.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thnx in advance.

One side of the problem follows directly from the fact I mentioned at the very beginnng i.e. if $X$ is separable then $S_X$ is separable since it is a subset of $X$.

For the other part I am completely stuck. I have taken a countable dense subset $D=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $S_X$ but can not find a way to construct a countable dense subset of $X$.

Please help me. Thnx again.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q} \cdot D$?

Comment: @gerw  You want to consider the set $\{rx_i\mid r\in \mathbb Q,i\in \mathbb N\}$? I am sorry but I can not find how that will work. Will you please explain?Thank you.

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: @gerw Thank you so much. Looking forward for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the set $\mathbb{Q}\cdot D = \{r \, x_i \mid r \in \mathbb{Q}, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$: for an arbitrary $x \in X$, you have $x = \|x\| \cdot x/\|x\|$, with $\|x\| \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x/\|x\| \in S_X$. The former can be approximated with an element from $\mathbb{Q}$ and the latter with an element from $D$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a confusion about what do you mean by "approximated" in both the cases. Will you please explain? It will be of great help to understand the solution. Thanx again

Comment: For every $\varepsilon > 0$, you find $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $| \|x\|-q | \le \varepsilon$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\| x/\|x\| - x_n\| \le \varepsilon$. Now, you can estimate $\|q \, x_n - x\|$ by using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have understood how you want to approach. Please see if it is correct or not. We choose $x_n \in D$ and $q\in \mathbb Q$ such that $||x-x_n||x||||<\frac{\epsilon}{||x||+1}||x||,|||x||-q|<\frac{\epsilon}{||x||+1}$ And then $||qx_n-x||\le||x-||x||x_n||+||x_n|||q-||x|||<\frac{\epsilon}{||x||+1}(||x||+1)$ (Since $||x_n||=1$) And hence $||qx_n-x||<\epsilon$ which is we required.
Am I correct in this?Thnx again

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.